# Find the number of real solutions of the equation $2^x+x^2=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, exponential-function, quadratics

My attempt is as follows:-

$$2^x+x^2=1$$
$$\left(1+x\cdot log(2)+\frac{x^2\cdot (log(2))^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3\cdot (log(2))^3}{3!}+\dots\right)+x^2=1$$
$$x\cdot log(2)\left(1+x^2+\frac{x\cdot log(2)}{2!}+\frac{x^2\cdot (log(2))^2}{3!}\right)=0$$

$$x=0, \left(1+x^2+\frac{x\cdot log(2)}{2!}+\frac{x^2\cdot (log(2))^2}{3!}\right)=0$$

$$x^2+\frac{x\cdot log(2)}{2!}+\frac{x^2\cdot (log(2))^2}{3!}+\dots=-1$$

Now I started to think when this can be negative, it can only be when x is negative.

I also thought about $$S=x^2+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{x^i\cdot (log(2))^i}{i+1}\right)$$. But I was not finding the way to transform it into telescopic series.

I am stuck here and not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, you really are overcomplicating things. There's no need to use the series expansion. First, just note that both $2^x$ and $x^2$ are increasing functions on $[0,\infty)$, which means that the equation $2^x+x^2=1$ can have at most one solution on this interval. Indeed it does have exactly one solution, given by $x=0$. And then note that the $2^x$ term becomes insignificant when $x\to-\infty$, so the function is decreasing on $(-\infty,a]$ for some $a<0$, and has exactly one solution here too. So the answer is $2$.

[image]

Comment: see $2^x$ is always the increasing the function on $(-\infty,\infty)$, but $-x^2+1$ is the parabola which is concave down parabola which will intersect x axis at 2 points, $(-1,1)$ and its peak point will have coordinates $(0,1)$ , now at this peak point $2^x$ will intersect with parabola , how can we say that there exists only one other point at which these two graphs will intersect.

Comment: see $2^x$ is always the increasing the function on (−∞,∞), but $−x^2+1$ is the parabola which is concave down parabola which will intersect x axis at $2$ points, $(−1,1)$ and its peak point will have coordinates $(0,1)$ , now at this peak point $2^x$ will intersect with parabola , how can we say that there exists only one other point at which these two graphs will intersect.

Comment: can you please answer my query

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. I didn't even look at those two functions, I looked at $f(x)=2^x+x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

[image]

Clearly $x=0$ is a solution.  The other can be seen from the graph.  (Numerical solution:  $x = -0.572195.$)

In short:  exactly two real solutions.

One function is always concave up, the other always concave down, so the maximum number of solutions is two, which is what we have.

Comment: see $2^x$ is always the increasing the function on (−∞,∞), but $−x^2+1$ is the parabola which is concave down parabola which will intersect x axis at $2$ points, $(−1,1)$ and its peak point will have coordinates $(0,1)$ , now at this peak point $2^x$ will intersect with parabola , how can we say that there exists only one other point at which these two graphs will intersect.

Comment: can you please answer my query

Comment: I guess the other point was found either by the graph or by numerical calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x)=2^x+x^2-1.$$
Its first and second derivatives are $$f'(x)=\ln2\cdot2^x+2x$$
and $$f''(x)=(\ln2)^2\cdot2^x+2.$$

Observe:

- Second derivative is strictly positive
- First derivative has one root at $x_{min}=\dfrac1{\ln2}W\bigg(\dfrac{(\ln 2)^2}2\bigg)\approx-0.28454$
- $f(x_{min})\approx-0.098034<0$

Therefore, $f(x)$ has two zeroes, and there are two real solutions to your equation.

Comment: I was wondering how did you conclude the last line from the above lines, I mean the line starting with "Therefore,...."?

Comment: $f(x)$ has a negative minimum value and is always concave up.  Therefore, its curve must pass through the $x$-axis twice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your remark about negative min. probably indicates real roots (not sure) but the rest of the argument does not lead to a solid statement about the roots (based on the little I know, at least).  Actually for the first argument, sin(x)-4 has many negative min. values below the x-axis but no real roots.

Comment: The intermediate value theorem tells us that if a function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$ has, WLOG, $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$, then there exists $c\in[a,b]$ where $f(c)=0$.  Since the function has values greater than $0$ and is always concave up, this tells us that there is exactly one zero on the interval $(x_{min},\infty)$ and exactly one zero on the interval $(-\infty,x_{min})$.

Comment: $y=\sin x-4$ does not have a strictly positive second derivative.

Comment: see $2^x$ is always the increasing the function on (−∞,∞), but $−x^2+1$ is the parabola which is concave down parabola which will intersect x axis at $2$ points, $(−1,1)$ and its peak point will have coordinates $(0,1)$ , now at this peak point $2^x$ will intersect with parabola , how can we say that there exists only one other point at which these two graphs will intersect.

Comment: can you please answer my query

Comment: You have not read my answer and tried to understand the answer I have provided.  You literally copied and pasted the same comment from the other answers.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will study it. As for your last comment, I am not sure who do you mean? Anyway, thank you.

Comment: I think that you missed a minus sign for $x_{min}$.

Answer (score 1):

*Too long for a comment.*

Starting from Andrew Chin's analysis, we could obtain a quite good estimate of the solution.

As said, the first derivative cancels at
$$x_*=-\frac{1}{\log (2)}W\left(\frac{\log ^2(2)}{2}\right)$$
Now, develop the function as a Taylor series around this point
$$f(x)=2^x+x^2-1=f(x_*)+\frac 12 f''(x_*)(x-x_*)^2+ O\big((x-x_*)^3\big)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the approximation is then
$$x_\pm=x_* \pm \sqrt{-2\frac {f(x_*)}{f''(x_*)}}$$ Computing, this would give as estimates $x_-=-0.5707$ and $x_+=0.0016$ while the exact solutions are $x_-=-0.5722$ and $x_+=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\log_2 t$ and recast $2^x+x^2=1$ as,

$$\log_2 t +\sqrt{1-t}=0$$

Apply a perturbation approximation around the base solution $t=\frac23$ to obtain an accurate algebraic solution for the root,

$$t_r=\frac{\ln16+\sqrt3 (\ln\frac49 -2)}{\ln8-3\sqrt3}$$

The root for $x_r=\log_2 t_r$ is

$$x_r=-0.57233\> (-0.57220)$$

with the exact value in parenthesis for comparison.

Comment: It would be nice to show how did you calculate $t$ in your second equation. It is far from obvious for me. Thanks.

Comment: @NoChance - The second equation results from a perturbation approximation in the $t$-coordination. Notice that the expression mostly involves 2s and 3s and their powers. It was done with 2/3 as a base solution. The actual derivation is bit involved and I did not bother to let it take up space. I thought the accuracy and the relative simplicity is more interesting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the method of perturbation is probably an advanced concept for this question. It would be good to mention this in the body of the answer. I will vote for the question since you have introduced a non-common way of approaching the answer, but I am not sure if your solution is correct.

Comment: @NoChance - Appreciate the suggestion; added to the answer